# Primefaces - Navigation menu, wrong highlighted menuitem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Avalon Theme. For navigation menu was used  `<pm:menu model = #{managedBean.panelMenuModel}/>` element.
Model elements returns {DefaultMenuItem, DefaultSubMenu, DefaultSubMenu ....}
Menu is rendering properly. But sometimes, when I was click a menu item, It highlighted wrong the current selected.

For exeample, I clicked 2.submenu>1.menuitem, it highlighted 4.submenu>3.menuitem.
But current url is 2.submenu>1.menuitem url

**#{managedBean.panelMenuModel}** = https://ibb.co/59R7BnN

And I shared you a gif https://ibb.co/PT69Lp2. The problem is exactly as you can see.
How can I fix that?

***Info : Primefaces 6.1 , Mojarra 2.2.11, Avalon 2.1.2 and SpringBoot***

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What information is missing for example?